# Grails copying Create button from create to edit pages doesn't work, what am I missing

Tags: grails, controller

I'm using the stock screens within grails for a few bits to save time.  I've got both an edit and a create view, both are pretty similar (the edit view has some extra hidden fields to store the ID of the scenario etc).

In my controller I have the basic methods, one called save one called update, they both end up going to a new saveAll method (the save method does a little bit beforehand to initially insert some table entries and get an id whereas the update just goes directly into the saveall method without doing anything else).

The saveall method does all the donkey work of clearing out/updating and inserting data into tables (as I use lots of join tables that need updating).

My thought process was that the create button goes through the save method, the update button goes through the update method.  So if I copy the "create" button from the create page and paste it into the edit page then I have effectively got a "clone" button (as it should go through the process of just inserting a new record rather than updating the existing one).

However, when I click that button nothing happens at all, it just goes back to the list view and I have no idea what I've missed. Probably something very fundamental, anyone got any clues?

The create button on the create page looks like so: -

Grails

```
 <g:submitButton name="create" class="save" value="${message(code: 'default.button.create.label', default: 'Create')}" />
```

Html

```
  <input id="create" class="save" type="submit" value="Create" name="create">
```

The same button copied to the edit page looks exactly the same, so why doesn't it do anything at all (I've even added in a println into the save method and that doesn't get hit at all).

Hoping someone can point out the obvious mistake I'm making here as I'm lost!

Comment: Make sure the edit form has set up the action parameter as you are using a submitButton.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, couldn't tell me where this gets set could you?  I've never had to do it manually...

Comment: Thanks for the pointer you made me realise what I was missing! :)

Comment: <g:form controller="yourController" action="yourAction" method="post">...</g:form>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I was being an idiot.  All I needed to do was to copy the save line and change the action "update" to "save" and hey presto all was fine.

So I copied : -

```
<g:actionSubmit class="save" action="update" value="${message(code: 'default.button.update.label', default: 'Update')}" />
```

And changed it to: -

```
<g:actionSubmit class="save" action="save" value="Clone" />
```

And all is now good!